# What Types of Questions Can I Expect in an AI/ML Summer Internship Interview?

Tags: career-path, interview, internship, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am currently preparing for interviews for summer internships in the field of Artificial Intelligence and Machine Learning. Given the highly specialized and rapidly evolving nature of this field, I am seeking guidance on the types of questions that might be asked during these interviews.

My background includes coursework and projects in AI/ML. Therefore, I am particularly interested in understanding what interviewers typically focus on. Are the questions primarily technical, testing specific knowledge and skills in AI/ML? Or do interviewers also emphasize soft skills, problem-solving abilities, and understanding of broader industry trends?

I also saw this question but I didn't find it similar: [What do professors expect during internship interview](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/173341/what-do-professors-expect-during-internship-interview).

Comment: Are these internships in academia, in industry, at a government lab, etc.?

Comment: I'm talking about internships in academia. @Aruralreader